# Accessing a python module in the containing package

Tags: python, module, package

I have a Python package `x` containing only:

```
x/__init__.py
x/spam.py
x/eggs.py
x/more/beans.py
```

`eggs` can access `spam` by:

```
from . import spam
```

but how is `beans` supposed to access `spam` internally?

```
from . import spam  <-- error
import spam         <-- error
```

Comment: `from x import spam` ? (this assumes that your program is being executed from the directory that contains the folder x, or your pythonpath includes that folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `from .. import spam`

Comment: you should really just be able to `import spam` (or maybe `from x import spam`)... if thats giving an error its probably an indication of poorly setup pythonpaths .... but +1 all the same for relative imports (beware this will not work in py < 2.7 ... you shouldnt really be using < py.27 if you are startign a new project)